# Can Phantasmal Force Incapacitate Someone?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions, illusion

The spell Phantasmal Force allows the caster to implant an illusion into a creature's mind. Would it be possible to use some form of illusion that would make the target believe it is incapacitated, so therefore it would be incapacitated?

Comment: We've marked your question as a dupe because it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why and we'll we what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!